# Why do my favourite tags look screwy only on travel.se?

Tags: support, tag-watching

I am active on a lot of SE sites. Some are beta and some are not. Recently, I added some fav tags here on travel because the volume finally warrants it. Alas, something is not right:

[image]

I don't have this problem on other beta sites, like scifi:

[image]

Nor on the main site, where I have more favs than will fit on the screen:

[image]

The oddness happens for me here on travel everywhere fav tags are shown but not in other places tags are shown such as "this question is tagged" lists.

I'm using IE 8 on Windows 7, 1366 x 768.

EDIT:

Ha! It also happens when tagging a question here on m.t.se:

[image]

Comment: Not for me. Have you set a custom font/size in your browser?

Comment: No, my browser is pretty much uncustomized.

Comment: FYI they look fine in Firefox. But I'm not going to start using FF for day to day use.

Comment: What browser is this in then?

Comment: It says in the question - IE8, Win7

Comment: I sometimes get slightly messy favourite tags with Windows 7 / Google Chrome. But never anything as bad as you get.

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 3):

The tags look like that in IE7 mode, so I suppose your IE was displaying travel.se (and only that site) in compatibility mode.

Comment: interesting ... from time to time when I comment or answer, my IE does balloon something about compatibility mode. I wonder if it's something in the HTML or an artifact of my occasionally-slow connection? If it happens again, I'll try deliberately fiddling with compat mode settings.

Comment: Hm, I just commented on a question, and during that process was put into compat mode (no idea why) but my tags are not messed up. FWIW.

Comment: But half an hour later, they are. Clicking the compat button (to turn it off, I think) fixes them. (Maybe the previously ok ones were cached?) I am going to file this under "don't understand" but if someone who actually knows CSS, compat mode etc learns anything from the data points, yay.

Comment: There was a post on some meta site (can't find it right now) where the user said this happened (IIRC) when submitting the comment via pressing Enter, but not when pressing the button. I couldn't reproduce that, but could you check if that's the same thing for you? In that case, it may be worth looking closer at it.

Comment: Seems like I do indeed go into compat mode (only on some sites, or only some of the time) when pressing Enter, and that it has other consequences too http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110452/has-something-changed-recently-that-would-affect-focus-for-keystrokes

Answer (score 2):

After looking crappy like that for days, when I finally get around to posting about it, they now look just fine. Thanks to whoever did whatever to make that happen.